# Comparing Uniform Random Variable

Tags: uniform-distribution

> $X,Y$ and $Z$ are uniformly distributed random variables on $(0,1)$
>   What is the probability that $X+Y>Z$?

I tried to do it geometrically and find the volume $x+y$ in the given limits i.e. $0$ to $1$ for both $x$ and $y$.
But that gives $P(x+y>z)=1$ which means no such examples exist for which $x+y< z$. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You tried to find $P(z<x+y)$ by 
$$
\int_0^1dx \int_0^1 dy \int_0^{x+y} 1\, dz
$$
which does work out to 1.  However, the range of $z <x+y$ is not $z\in(0,x+y)$ because $z$ cannot be more than 1. When $y>1-x$,$z$ can never exceed $x+y$, but you should integrate only up to $1$, not $x+y$.  This explains the extra magnitude that brings that integral up to 1; the volume you shouldn't have added when $z>1$ amounts to \frac{1}{6}.

The correct integral to compute $P(z>x+y)$ is 
$$
\int_0^1dx \int_0^1 dy \int_{z=x+y}^1 1\, dz = \int_0^1dx \int_0^1\left[ 
1-x-y]
 \right]dy = \int_0^1 \left[(1-x)-x(1-x)-\frac{(1-x)^2}{2}\right]dx =\frac{1}{6}
$$

Comment: so i believe that is the only caveat i have to check in such questions (for geometric solutions). The fact that lower and upper limits of z should not exceed the range over which its uniformly distributed.